# How should I statically cast a std::shared_ptr of one type to a std::shared_ptr of another

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

My code is below. I want to convert `std::shared_ptr<void>` to `std::shared_ptr<C>`, but it didn't work.

I got the following error:

```
main.cpp:74:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<C>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<void>&)’
     std::shared_ptr<C> c = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<C>>(ptr);
```

My code:

```
class C
{
public:
    C() {}
    int val;
    int set;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<C> cc = std::make_shared<C>();
    cc->val = 1;
    cc->set = 2;
    
    std::shared_ptr<void> ptr = cc;

    std::shared_ptr<C> c = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<C>>(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smart pointers have [special cast functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I try to use static_pointer_cast. 
I got this error. I have no idea about this.
```
main.cpp:74:67: error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<C> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<C>’ requested
     std::shared_ptr<C> c = static_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<C>>(ptr);
```

Comment: You need  `std::static_pointer_cast<C>` (not `static_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<C>>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to cast a `shared_ptr<X>` to `shared_ptr<Y>` you need to use one of the [special cast functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

These functions:

> Creates a new instance of std::shared_ptr whose stored pointer is
> obtained from r's stored pointer using a cast expression.

For static cast this would be `static_pointer_cast`:

```
std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::static_pointer_cast<C>(ptr);
```